# Bootstrap ListBox with post option

Tags: html, listbox

I want to display two listboxes like in C# to add or remove items.

[image: ASP ListBox]

Is there a option in twitter bootstrap?

I tried out the

```
<div class="list-group"></div>
```

But there is no option to post this data to the next page without a js function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe bootstrap duallistbox plugin -> http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/ will suit your needs?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is what i looked for :-)